# Rezize NSWindow from top

Tags: cocoa, resize, frame, nswindow

I want to shrink a NSWindow, by changing the height of the frame and having that come off of the top of the window.
I tried:

```
NSRect frame = [mainWindow frame];
frame.origin.y += 71;
frame.size.height -= 71;
[mainWindow setFrame:frame display:YES animate:YES];
```

But it made the window smaller from the bottom, not the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cocoa on OS X, the origin is in the bottom left corner of the screen. This means that increasing the y position of a window will move it up the screen. Since you want to change the top of your window, you want the bottom corner to stay in place, which means you should not change your origin. Simply changing the height will cause your window to shrink from the top.

```
NSRect frame = [mainWindow frame];
frame.size.height -= 71;
[mainWindow setFrame:frame display:YES animate:YES];
```

Comment: That didn't quite do the trick. Pretty much the window shrank from the bottom, and then shifted down.

Comment: That's interesting. It's working fine for me. Are you doing anything else to the window at about the same time?

Comment: No just that... but yeah the bottom disappears, where I want the top to disappear.